# UML: Why associations are not shown in Object Diagram in Visio 2003?

Tags: uml, associations, visio, class-diagram, object-diagram

I am working with Visio 2003; full name is **Microsoft Office Visio for Enterprise Architects (11.8328.8405) SP3**.

I have 2 classes `Job` and `Task`. These are the rules:

- Each `Job` has 1 or more corresponding `Task`s.
- A `Task` cannot exist without a `Job`.

This is the **Class Diagram** I have build which includes 2 **classes** and 1 **composition association**:

[image: Class Diagram]

Now I am trying to build **Object Diagram**. Suppose I have a Job **Close Payroll** which has 3 Tasks:

1. **Run Payroll**
2. **Verify Payroll Data**
3. **Transmit Payroll**

I created the **Object Diagram** this way so far:

[image: Object Diagram]

The problem I am having is with the associations in **Object Diagram**. I was expecting that the association between `Job` and `Task` will automatically show in **Object Diagram** as the way it has been defined in **Class Diagram**. But it did not happen. What I am doing wrong here?  Do I have to define that association again in **Object Diagram**? I hope not.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances are no classes and thus do not have associations. Instances are connected via `Link`s which are not `Association`s but instantiations of the latter. See also [uml-diagrams.org](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#link)

Comment: Visio is not a real CASE tool, it's only supporting the very basic logic but in general it's tool to draw diagrams rather than build models. I'm afraid you simply expect too much from the tool. If you want to benefit from a model building you should consider some real modeling tool.

Comment: @Ister I thought so. You should post that as answer, since it actually answers the OP's question.

Comment: I meant to post it as an answer XD . I was answering on a mobile and simply misclicked. Thanks, posted now as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Visio is not a real CASE tool, it's only supporting the very basic logic but in general it's tool to draw diagrams rather than build models. I'm afraid you simply expect too much from the tool. If you want to benefit from a model building you should consider some real modeling tool.